# Outlook 2007 auto-delete e-mails in a certain category after X duration

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, archiving

I get two kinds of e-mail: Discussion and Notifications.  Notifications are auto-generated e-mails for things like code updates, issue tracking updates, and so forth.  I have filters set up that give them a "Notification" category.

I want to keep the discussions indefinitely, since you never know when you might need the info from an e-mail six months ago.  But, the notifications are ephemeral, and there is no need to have them clog disk space.

Is there a way to make Outlook auto-archive/auto-delete/purge/expire/whatever these e-mails based on the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just wrote my first Outlook macro - so don't blame me if it deletes all your mails. Backup before you try! :)

In Outlook go to *Tools > Macros > Macro*. Enter the name you want to give the macro. I named mine "Delete_Old_Notifications".

Here's the macro code I wrote:

```
Sub Delete_Old_Notification()
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim item As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Action As Integer
    Dim Categories, Category

    Action = 0

    For Each item In inbox.Items
    If Len(item.Categories & "") > 0 Then
        Categories = Split(item.Categories, ";")

        For Each Category In Categories
        Select Case LCase(Trim(Category))
            Case "notification":
            If DateDiff("d", item.ReceivedTime, Now) > 14 Then
                Action = 1
            End If
        End Select
        Next
    End If

    Select Case Action
        Case 1: MsgBox ("Delete '" & item.Subject & "'") 'item.Delete
    End Select

    Action = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

(Could be shorter, yes - but I built it to be extensible.)

Notes:

1. It looks in the standard inbox. If you want another folder, you have to modify the "Set inbox" folder. To look in subfolders of the inbox, add **.Folders("foldername")** at the end of the line
2. Currently it checks if the mail has a category "notification". If you want another category, insert that in the **Case**. Just make it lower case because I convert them all to lower case - just to be sure.
3. Currently it affects mails with an age of 14 days or above. See that in the **If DateDiff** line.
4. Currently it does not actually delete, it just shows a notification. To make it actually work you need to remove the MsgBox near the bottom of the Sub and keep the line like this:

   ```
       Case 1: item.Delete
   ```

You might want to look at these two forum posts to find out...

- how to [autorun the macro when starting Outlook](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/outlook-2007-run-macro-startup-t3720671.html)
- how to [sign your macro to allow Outook to run it](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm)